how to break page when sidenote/marginnote can not be placed?
I have a text to layout in a tufte-style with many sidenotes/marginnotes/marginpar. Occasionally notes for a line cannot be placed on the page. Depending on the package used they either stick out at the bottom or are move to the next page, which are both not acceptable in my case.
I wish that lines with marginpar which cannot be place on the page cause a page break as indicated in the MWE and the line including the side note and the marginpar are moved to the next page. It is acceptable that the main column of the page in such cases is not filled. If the \newpage is inserted, the expected behavior is achieved.
I have edited the MWE to clarify that the margin note is not always at the end of the paragraph and the paragraph should be broken at the line before the line with the note - and the line not justified and continued without indent for a new paragraph on the next page.
The answer from @John Kormylo works for the question as initially posed and I hope can be adapted to the more precise problem
A MWE is
\documentclass{article}

    \newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit met, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, lacerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida.  }

    \newcommand{\maintext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida   mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus   et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. }

%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{marginfit}
%\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}
    \maintext NOTE1 \marginpar{1 \filltext} \maintext
    
    \maintext NOTE2 \marginpar{2 \filltext}
    
    \maintext THE PARAGRAPH SHOULD BE BROKEN ON THE LINE 
%        \newpage 
          BEFORE THE NOTE NOTE3 \marginpar{3 \filltext} AND CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE WITHOUT INDENT \maintext
    
    \maintext rutrum. NOTE4  \marginpar{4 \filltext} and some more text.
    
    \maintext rutrum. NOTE5 \marginpar{5 \filltext} \maintext
    
\end{document}

This question is similar to this and this I posed without a MWE but the answers did not deal with my expected behavior.

The first step is to keep track how full the margin is, hense \margintotal.  This also uses \splitpar and \continuepar to split the last line of the paragraph off before breaking the page.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida.  }

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{marginfit}
%\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{placeins}

\newlength{\margintotal}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\global\margintotal=0pt}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}
\newcommand{\marginpage}[1]{\savebox{\marginbox}{\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{#1}}%
  \ifdim\ht\marginbox>\dimexpr \textheight-\margintotal\relax
    \par\newpage
  \fi
  \global\advance\margintotal by \dimexpr \ht\marginbox+\dp\marginbox\relax
  \continuepar\marginpar{\box\marginbox}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
\splitpar{rutrum. note1}\marginpage{1 \filltext}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
\splitpar{rutrum. note2}\marginpage{2 \filltext}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
\splitpar{rutrum. note3}\marginpage{3 \filltext}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
\splitpar{ rutrum. note4}\marginpage{4 \filltext}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
\splitpar{rutrum. note5}\marginpage{5 \filltext}
    
\end{document}


Not what you asked for, but this will break a marginpar if it overlaps the bottom of the page and moves the rest to the next page (if there is a next page).
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida.  I added a little extra.}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{marginfix}
%\marginskip{\intextsep}
\usepackage{marginfit}
%\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}
\newlength{\margintotal}
\newif\ifaftermargin% to handle multiple overages
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\global\margintotal=\dimexpr \ht\marginbox+\dp\marginbox\relax
  \global\aftermarginfalse}

\newcommand{\marginpage}[1]{% #1 = \marginpar text
  \global\setbox\marginbox=\vbox{\hsize=\marginparwidth
    \parindent=0pt
    %\sloppy
    \unvbox\marginbox
    #1
    \vskip\intextsep}
  \ifaftermargin
  \else
    \ifdim\ht\marginbox>\dimexpr \textheight-\margintotal\relax
      \setbox1=\vsplit\marginbox to \dimexpr \textheight-\margintotal\relax
      \marginpar{\unvbox1}%
      \global\margintotal=\textheight
      \afterpage{\marginpar{\unvbox\marginbox}}%
      \aftermargintrue
    \else
      \global\advance\margintotal by \dimexpr \ht\marginbox+\dp\marginbox\relax
      \marginpar{\unvbox\marginbox}%
    \fi
  \fi}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. note1\marginpage{1 \filltext}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. note2\marginpage{2 \filltext}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. note3\marginpage{3 \filltext}
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. note4\marginpage{4 \filltext}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. note5\marginpage{5 \filltext}
    
\end{document}


Thank you for your solution, which works for the original example. Can it be changed to work with notes in the middle of a line? and then not justify the line and start the next line not with an indent (i.e. not a paragraph break)?  I can partially understand how you address the issue, but my understanding ot LaTeX is not sufficient to improve it myself.

Anything that will break a page will also break a paragraph.  You can run \marginpage without \splitpar to see where the end of each line is.  It just won't move any text to the next page.

Unfortunately I have about 30 cases where a marginnote runs over at the bottom; therefore a manual approach (which must be done in many cases repeatedly) can only help at the very end. Is it possible to change your code to not breakt the line (ie have it continue) after the call to marginpage and wait with the pagebreak till the line is filled as well? (I am less worried about the indent after the break). Thank you for your help!

That sounds like what happens when you don't use \splitpar, unless I misunderstood your intent.

I have tried to understand the code you suggest and wonder if your command marginpage which I think executes \par\newpage when the page or the margin is full, could break at the beinning of the current line (i.e. a few words before the sidenote)?  This seems to me - not understanding internals of TeX - similar to the situation when a word is added to a line or page, which will not fit and the break must come before. It would be most helpful for the book layout I try to achieve.

LaTeX formats the entire paragraph then adds it to the page.   In order to break off the last line one would have to first put the paragraph into a \vbox, split off the last line with \vsplit, then add the top part to the document (using \unvbox).  Doable, but requires the entire paragraph be processed by a command.
